# SQL Server calling URI functions

Tags: sql-server, iis

I have a client with SQL Server 2012 running a web application on an IIS web server. Is there any hook between SQL Server and IIS such as a SQL function that can retrieve the URI from IIS that made the database request? My ultimate goal is to write some triggers that takes information from the URL and records some information from the URL in the database.

Comment: IIS is a separate process so it has no way to know anything about the web request behind the actual sql session. also knowing that usually connection pooling is active it is very unlikely that any information about the web session could pass from IIS to SQL without explicitly setting it as a SQL parameter in the call.

Comment: That's what I was thinking was likely. I was hoping there was some sort of hook that would make something like this possible.